# Automatically merging multiple Pydantic models with overlapping fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

It is kind of difficult to accurately phrase my question in one sentence.

I have the following models:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Detail1(BaseModel):
    round: bool
    volume: float


class AppleData1(BaseModel):
    origin: str
    detail: Detail1


class Detail2(BaseModel):
    round: bool
    weight: float


class AppleData2(BaseModel):
    origin: str
    detail: Detail2
```

Here `AppleData1` has an attribute `detail` which is of the type `Detail1`. `AppleData2` has an attribute `detail` which is of the type `Detail2`. I want to make an `Apple` class which contains all the attributes of `AppleData1` and `AppleData2`.

### Question (How to implement the algorithm?)

Do you have a generic approach to implement this algorithm:

- Whenever `AppleData1` and `AppleData2` have an attribute of the same name:

  - If they are of the same type, use one of them. For example, `AppleData1.origin` and `AppleData2.origin` are both of the type `str`. So `Apple.origin` is also of type `str`.
  - If they are of different types, merge them. For example, `AppleData1.detail` and `AppleData2.detail`, they are of type `Detail1` and `Detail2` respectively. So `Apple.detail` should contain all the inner attributes.
- Any common inner attribute is always for the same physical quantity. So overwriting is allowed. For example, `Detail1.round` and `Detail2.round` are both of type `bool`. So the resulting `Apple.detail.round` is also of type `bool`.

### Expect Results

The end results should be equivalent to the `Apple` model below. (The definition of `Detail` class below is only used to make the code below complete. The generic approach should not hard-code the `Detail` class.)

```py
class Detail(BaseModel):
    round: bool
    volume: float    
    weight: float

class Apple(BaseModel):
    origin: str
    detail: Detail
```

### My Solution (bad example)

```py
class Detail(Detail1, Detail2):
    pass


class Apple(AppleData1, AppleData2):
    origin: str
    detail: Detail

print(Apple.schema_json())
```

This solution works but it is too-specific.

1. Here I need to pin-point that `detail` attribute from `AppleData1` and `AppleData2`, and specifically create the `Detail` class from specifically `Detail1` and `Detail2`.
2. I need to pin-point that `origin` is a common attribute of the same type (`str`). So I specifically hard-coded `origin: str` in the definition of the `Apple` class.

Comment: _"2. I need to pin-point that `origin` is a common attribute of the same type"_ No, that was redundant. Inheritance takes care of that. No need to specify `Apple.origin` at all. I understand the other point though. You want to avoid explicitly creating the the new `Detail` class.

Comment: What is supposed to happen, if `Detail1` and `Detail2` both have the same field `foo`, but with _different_ types, e.g. `int` and `str` respectively? Should normal inheritance precedence rules based on the order determine the resulting type? Or should the resulting type be a _union_, i.e. `foo: int | str`? And should that behavior also apply to the "top-level" model `Apple` for its non-sub-model fields like `origin` for example?

Comment: What about other field information such as `default` values, `alias` definitions or value constraints like `max_length`? How should those be handled, when "merging" fields?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, thanks for your comments. Suppose `Detail1` and `Detail2` both have the same field `foo`. If `foo` is a built-in type like `str`, `float`, `int`, `bool`, `list`, and `dict`, then `Detail1.foo` and `Detail2.foo` are always of the same type (not like one is `str` and the other is `int`). If the `foo` is a type defined as a child-class of BaseModel, then, the inner attributes of `Detail1.foo` and `Detail2.foo` can be different.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, any other field information like `default`, `max_length` are not needed in my project. So no need to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simplified solution

Implementing a custom recursive version of the [`create_model`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) function to dynamically construct a "combined" model class should work:

```py
from typing import TypeGuard, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
from pydantic.fields import SHAPE_SINGLETON

M = TypeVar("M", bound=BaseModel)


def is_pydantic_model(obj: object) -> TypeGuard[type[BaseModel]]:
    return isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, BaseModel)


def create_combined_model(
    __name__: str,
    /,
    model1: type[M],
    model2: type[M],
) -> type[M]:
    field_overrides = {}
    for name, field1 in model1.__fields__.items():
        field2 = model2.__fields__.get(name)
        if field2 is None:
            continue
        if is_pydantic_model(field1.type_):
            assert field1.shape == SHAPE_SINGLETON, "No model collections allowed"
            assert is_pydantic_model(field2.type_), f"{name} with different types"
            sub_model = create_combined_model(
                f"Combined{field1.type_.__name__}{field2.type_.__name__}",
                field1.type_,
                field2.type_,
            )
            field_overrides[name] = (sub_model, field1.field_info)
        else:
            assert field1.annotation == field2.annotation, f"Different types"
    return create_model(__name__, __base__=(model1, model2), **field_overrides)  # type: ignore
```

This incorporates your restrictions/assumptions about the models that *can* be combined that you elaborated on in your comments.

It does not support combining fields that are annotated with `C[M]`, where `C` is any generic collection type and `M` is a subclass of `BaseModel`. That is what the `SHAPE_SINGLETON` check assures. It would possible to incorporate logic that allows combining models *and* retaining the shape of the field (e.g. `list[Detail1]` and `list[Detail2]`), but I left that out because you did not ask for that explicitly and it is a bit more complicated.

### Demo

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class AppleBase(BaseModel):
    foo: str


class DetailBase(BaseModel):
    round: bool


class Detail1(DetailBase):
    volume: float


class AppleData1(AppleBase):
    bar: int
    detail: Detail1


class Detail2(DetailBase):
    weight: float


class AppleData2(AppleBase):
    baz: float
    detail: Detail2


Apple = create_combined_model("Apple", AppleData1, AppleData2)
print(Apple.schema_json(indent=4))
```

### Output

```json
{
    "title": "Apple",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "title": "Foo",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "baz": {
            "title": "Baz",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "detail": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/CombinedDetail1Detail2"
        },
        "bar": {
            "title": "Bar",
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "foo",
        "baz",
        "detail",
        "bar"
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "CombinedDetail1Detail2": {
            "title": "CombinedDetail1Detail2",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "round": {
                    "title": "Round",
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "weight": {
                    "title": "Weight",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "volume": {
                    "title": "Volume",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "round",
                "weight",
                "volume"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Caveats

An obvious drawback to this solution is that because it *dynamically* creates the model class, it is impossible to properly convey the type of the resulting model in terms of static analysis.

The way I wrote it now, the function is [generic](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) to the greatest extent possible in that the returned type will be inferred as either the **joined** or the **union** type, depending on the static type checker, of the two input models `model1` and `model2`.

In the demo example this means some type checkers like Mypy for example will infer the type of `Apple` to be `AppleBase` (**join**). This is of course not *wrong*, but it is not as specific as we might like because it fails to account for the existence of the `bar`, `baz`, and `detail` attributes.

A type checker that uses **unions** instead might infer the type as `AppleData1 | AppleData2` instead. (I have not tested it, but I believe Pyright does this.) This may or may not be preferable, because it would at least *always* cover the existence of a `detail` attribute (albeit with yet another union type of `Detail1 | Detail2`), but it would be ambiguous whether or not `Apple` has a `bar` *or* a `baz` attribute to such a type checker.

The ideal solution would be to define the return type as the **intersection** of the two model types passed into it. But unfortunately [we do not have that typing construct](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) (yet).

All of this has no effect on the *runtime* behavior of the constructed class of course, but it is not ideal for IDE auto-suggestions for example.

Consequently, your initial *explicit* approach of using multiple inheritance for all the models involved is still something I would recommend, unless your models become *very* large/complex and numerous.